# What's the equalivent of SAS function INTNX in Teradata?

Tags: sas, teradata

I have a Proc SQL code from SAS which I want to convert to a Teradata readable code to create a new table view. The code has an intnx function command to join two date fields to find the day value and then subtracted by a month renewal date field to get the final value. The issue I am having is figuring how to convert the code into Teradata layman terms in order to pull the data.

Here is the code:

[INTNX CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srj9W.jpg)

```
MTURE_RNW_DT  OPEN_RNW_DT   BNK_TRM_IN_MTH_VAL
9/8/2005       9/8/2004     12
3/11/2013      9/11/2011    18
11/20/2014     5/20/2014    6
10/20/2013     1/26/2012    21
12/11/2011    12/10/2008    36
3/23/2015      3/22/2012    36
5/4/2010        3/5/2010    2
8/21/2012      1/29/2011    18
5/4/2014       4/27/2012    24
```

Comment: What does the function actually do? It looks to me like you're trying to calculate months between two dates?  That's just `months_between( date1, date2)`.

Comment: I am trying to find out how to get the months value from what is the brackets and then minus from what the intnx value is. How do I convert it into SQL by pulling in the fields from the table. Here is the code:                              SELECT DISTINCT bnk_acct_key,snpsht_dt,OPEN_RNW_DT,MTURE_RNW_DT
,BNK_TRM_IN_MTH_VAL AS month_value
,MTURE_RNW_DT-intnx('month', OPEN_RNW_DT, BNK_TRM_IN_MTH_VAL, 's') AS day_value
FROM V_CLB_BASIC.VC_BNK_TM_ACCT
WHERE snpsht_dt IN (SELECT Max(snpsht_dt) FROM V_CLB_BASIC.VC_BNK_TM_ACCT)
;

Comment: Looking at documentation, it seems `intnx('month',_date_,_integer_,'s')` may be equivalent to Teradata `ADD_MONTHS( _date_,_integer_ )`

Comment: The ADD_MONTHS addition worked :). Thank you.